# Where layer notes in QGIS are saved

Tags: qgis-3

We can add Layer Notes to every Layer in QGIS.
Where is this info stored in QGIS?

Comment: I have found this question (https://github.com/qgis/QGIS-Documentation/issues/6670) on Github. It doens't say whre the Layer Notes are being saved but I thought you might ask there as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notes are saved in the QGIS project file (.qgz or .qgs) per layer and if you save a layer file (.qlr) for a layer with notes, the notes will also be saved to the .qlr file.

There's some information about the file formats [in the documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/appendices/qgis_file_formats.html), though not specifically about layer notes.

If you open a .qgs (unzip a .qgz) or .qlr in a text editor (they are XML) you can find the `<userNotes>` element which contains the notes in encoded HTML format, e.g.

```
<userNotes value="&lt;!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN&quot; &quot;http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd&quot;>&#xa;&lt;html>&lt;head>&lt;meta name=&quot;qrichtext&quot; content=&quot;1&quot; />&lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;>&#xa;p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }&#xa;&lt;/style>&lt;/head>&lt;body style=&quot; font-family:'Liberation Sans'; font-size:10pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;&quot;>&#xa;&lt;p style=&quot; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;&quot;>Note todo list&lt;/p>&lt;/body>&lt;/html>"/>
```